# SetProcessDPIAware seems not to work under windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, screen-resolution, dpi

I am trying to get the real screen resolution (in pixels) in a windows C++ app. When the windows dpi setting is changed, I get the virtual (adjusted) resolution instead of the real one. I have tried using SetProcessDPIAware, SetProcessDpiAwareness (with all three enumerated values as arguments) and a true setting in a manifest. In all three cases, the code works fine (i.e. shows the real resolution) in my windows 7 PC but not in a Win 10 one (here it ignores the DPI Aware setting and returns the adjusted resolution).

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <VersionHelpers.h>
#include <ShellScalingAPI.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
char *cBuffer2 ;

  cBuffer2 = (char *)malloc(3000) ;
  if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
  {
//    SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE);
      int result = SetProcessDPIAware();

      sprintf(cBuffer2,"SetProcessDPIAware() result: [%i]\n",result) ;

      int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
      int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
      sprintf(cBuffer2,"%s#1:\nHeight: [%i]\nwidth: [%i]\n",cBuffer2,height,width) ;


      HWND hwnd = (HWND)atoi(lpCmdLine) ;
      HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
      MONITORINFO info;
      info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
      GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info);
      int monitor_width = info.rcMonitor.right - info.rcMonitor.left;
      int monitor_height = info.rcMonitor.bottom - info.rcMonitor.top;
      sprintf(cBuffer2,"%s#2:\nHeight: [%i]\nwidth: [%i]\n",cBuffer2,monitor_height,monitor_width) ;

  }

  MessageBox(0,cBuffer2,"SHOWRES.EXE",MB_OK) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

The manifest I tried using is the following one:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Very hard to tell what you have done here. You seem to be lots of things all at the same time. Why don't you pick one and stick to it. I suggest you use the manifest approach. You didn't tell us what the output was.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, I try many different approaches because none works.As I said in the original post, under windows 7 I get the expected result (i.e. the real resolution of the display), but under windows 10 I get the virtual resolution (the same I get without any DPI aware setting).

Comment: The problem is that we don't know which approach you want, and what you have tried. I'd prefer you to pick one approach, and present a [mcve].

Comment: I believe I have been very clear in what I have tried and what results I got. The verifiable example is the C/C++ code included in my original post. As to which approach I want, the answer is any that works. The manifest would probably be the best one since it is the approach recommended by microsoft.

Comment: So you used a manifest and called `SetProcessDPIAware`. Why did you do that? You should pick one. You should also show the output of your program. And you should tell us your DPI settings on all machines. In any case, I'm going to give up at this point. It is too hard to extract more information. Good luck.

Comment: I tried your example code, and with just `SetProcessDPIAware` it appears to work fine in Windows 10 (gets the true resolution of the monitor).

Comment: I tried too and it seems to work. You didn't zero `cBuffer2` before writing to it.

Comment: So it seems that nobody can reproduce the issue. This is why I asked for a [mcve].

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: Thanks for your help. It would seem that there is something in the specific machine that causes the problem. I 'll have to investigate further. Will get back if I find something.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani: Thanks for your help too.

Comment: I meant to say zero `cBuffer2` before *reading* from it in `sprintf(cBuffer2,"%s ... %i\n",cBuffer2,result) ;`

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani: You are absolutely right. In my test program I had more sprintf() calls before that. I 'll fix it for clarity.

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements/

Answer (score 11):

I finally found out what is happening, with the help of Jonathan Potter and Barmak Shemirani: Windows 10, unlike previous versions of windows, allows the user to change the dpi settings 'on the fly', without the need to log out and login again. I was running the tests on a win 10 machine which normally has standard (100%) settings. So I would change the setting to 150%, run the app and get the wrong results.

Jonathan and Barmak's answers indicated that there is something in the specific PC's settings, not in the program or win 10 in general, that was causing my problems. So I tried the following:

```
- changed DPI settings to 150%
- logged out
- logged in again
- ran the program
```

And I got the correct results (real screen resolution, vs adjusted one).

So it seems that in order for SetProcessDPIAware (and the related approaches: SetProcessDpiAwareness() and manifest with true) to work correctly, one has to log out and login again after changing the DPI setting and before running the program.

Thanks again, Jonathan and Barmak!

Comment: This may not be helpful, but the documentation for SetProcessDpiAware() specifically says not to use it in later versions of Windows (as per Requirements section in MSDN for that function) and that SetProcessDpiAwareness() should be used *instead* (and that it should be called at most once - whether by manifest or by code).