# SetProcessDpiAwareness error code

Tags: windows, delphi, dpi

I'm adding a call to the SetProcessDpiAwareness windows function as the first thing in my Delphi XE7 application (after dynamically loading the shcore DLL). I know it is preferable to use a manifest to set the DPIAware value and I've got that working separately and will use it eventually. However during development I want to use a command line parameter to set DPIAwareness value, otherwise I have to rebuild the app to change this status.

The problem is that SetProcessDpiAwareness returns the error code $800700A0.
That is not documented in the function description, what does the code mean?

Ah I've found it, thanks to the answer to look at the parameter, I had declared the function type wrong, I had:

TSetDPIFunc = function (const PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS) : HRESULT; stdcall;

but PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS was not defined as an enum.
Changed to the following and it now works fine:

TSetDPIFunc = function (const x: Integer) : HRESULT; stdcall;

Comment: Are you calling `SetProcessDPIAwareness` or `SetProcessDPIAware`? The title suggests the former. The latter does not return any error code, a nonzero return means the function have succeeded. Please edit the question to clear.

Comment: In case you are indeed calling SetProcessDPIAwareNESS, please show us with which argument you call it!

Comment: The function is SetProcessDpiAwareness, sorry typo in original post.

Answer (score 1):

`0x8007XXXX` is a [Win32 error code encapsulated in a COM `HRESULT`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061103-07/?p=29133) using [`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746.aspx). `WIN32_FROM_HRESULT(0x800700A0)` gives `0xA0`, i.e. error code 160, which is [`ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS)  ("One or more of the input parameters are not correct").

It makes no sense for me though that you get this error, since *this function doesn't even take any arguments*!

So the only thing I can think of would be that it has something to with [the issue described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156809/1871033), assuming you changed the DPI settings yourself for testing and it failed then:

> So it seems that in order for SetProcessDPIAware (and the related approaches: SetProcessDpiAwareness() and manifest with true) to work correctly, one has to log out and login again after changing the DPI setting and before running the program.

By the way, in case this is helpful: For testing manifests without totally rebuilding, you could use [`mt.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649(VS.85).aspx) to attach a manifest to your application from the command line.

Comment: You can also save the manifest content to a separate `.manifest` file in the same folder as the executable, instead of compiling it into a resource at all.  For example, if your app's executable is named `MyApp.exe`, save the manifest to `MyApp.exe.manifest`. Then you can simply edit the file as needed between runs.

Comment: Only if you don't have a manifest already embedded, which might be the default from the compiler (because it's encouraged by Microsoft as well). Since Windows Vista, external manifests will be ignored if an embedded one exists.

Comment: You can turn off the default embedded manifest in the Project Options.